# Calling endEditing:YES on view controller fails to hide keyboard but returns YES as if it did

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, uitextfield, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` in a `UITableViewCell` and my `UITableViewController` is the delegate of that `UITextView`. For some reason if I return `NO` in the delegate method `textViewShouldEndEditing:` after calling `[self.view endEditing:YES]` (where self is the `UITableViewController`) the keyboard still does not hide **BUT** `[self.view endEditing:YES]` returns `YES`

As per the apple docs for `endEditing:`:

> Return Value: YES if the view resigned the first responder status or NO if it did

Shouldn't `endEditing:` return `NO` in this case? Or are resigning first responder status and dismissing the keyboard two different things? If they do mean the same thing, is this method returning an incorrect value? I'm a bit confused about how they are related.

Comment: Pls improve the wording because now you say you return NO, and few words later you say it returns YES. which cannot be both true. So which method returns what?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I just made a small change that should clear it up.

Comment: Where does "self" refer to in the [self endEditing:YES] call refer to?

Comment: You could describe us what you want to achieve in the program because us just trying to debug your code, but not really understanding what it should ultimately do is probably not the best way to solve the issue.

Comment: This is more an API question more than anything.  I solved the issue in a another way. I will update the question again to resolve confusion.